# Search users with CQ5 Query Builder

Tags: aem

We are using Adobe CQ5 with users organized in several trees (e.g., `/home/users/internalUsers`, `/home/users/guests, ...).

I am trying to find a user in any tree. I was able to

```
http://localhost:4900/bin/querybuilder.json?type=rep:User&nodename=*username
```

and I get

```
{"success":true,"results":1,"total":1,"offset":0,"hits" [{"path":"/home/users/testUsers/u/username","excerpt":"","name": ....
```

but this will match any username *ending* in `username`. If I remove the `*` or put a `/` I don't find any match.

I tried

```
http://localhost:4900/bin/querybuilder.json?type=rep:User&nodename=username
http://localhost:4900/bin/querybuilder.json?type=rep:User&nodename=/username
http://localhost:4900/bin/querybuilder.json?type=rep:User&nodename=*/username
http://localhost:4900/bin/querybuilder.json?type=rep:User&nodename=*%2Fusername
```

without success.

Is there a way to reliably find a user among several paths?

**Edit**

I solved the original problem (searching for a user) with:

```
http://localhost:4900/bin/querybuilder.json?type=rep:User&property=rep:principalName&property.value=username
```

It would still be interesting to know how to search for a node with a given name.

Answer (score 2):

the nodename property that you've mentioned above does seem to be for this. [Adobe docs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-3/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html#Find%20jar%20files%20and%20order%20them,%20newest%20first) even use it as an example when demoing the query builder tool! This works in my local environment, even with some rudimentary regex, e.g.:

```
http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?nodename=cq-*-5.3.[4-9].jar
```

(Will match CQ jars from v5.3.4+, excluding those from v5.3.2. I can't get multiple character matches using ([a-z]*) via REST though — presume I have the syntax incorrect.)

Or do you mean another property when you say nodename? — presume you mean the name as in the directory structure.

Best,

Dave